# SSIS from Oracle Source

Tags: ssis

I am fairly new to SSIS. I am trying to load data from an Oracle Source. I have Oracle client 9i installed. I have the Attunity as well.

On the Oracle Connection Manager editor, what is the TNS service name? And could you also have the steps to follow? I want to see if I am doing it right.

Comment: Hey guys..I have figured it out,its like the db name in sql server.Thanks guys...I still appreciate your opinion.

Comment: You should post this as an answer to your own question to help others in the community who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out: It's like the db name in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the IP and db name.

[image: IP and db name]